# How do I via reflection in C# call a method that takes a 'method group' ie. Action<> or Func<>

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, reflection, delegates

I have a method with this signature, and another method that will be the used as the *Action*

```
ProcessFile(Uri uri, Action<Uri> callWhenDone);

void WhenDone(Uri uri);
```

Now I'm trying to use the *Invoke* method on *MethodInfo* ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.invoke.aspx)). But *parameters* is and object array. Which does not accept a 'method group'.

```
var methodInfo = myClass.GetType().GetMethod("nameOfMethod");

var methodParams = new object { new Uri(), WhenDone }; //<-- unable to just do this

methodInfo.Invoke(myClass, methodParams);
```

**How do I pass the method group, or a delegate to the method ProcessFile using *Invoke* or similar?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
var methodParams = new object { new Uri(), (Action<Uri>)((u) => WhenDone(u)) };
```

or

```
var methodParams = new object { new Uri(), (Action<Uri>)WhenDone };
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var methodInfo = myClass.GetType().GetMethod("nameOfMethod");

Action<Uri> action = WhenDone;
var methodParams = new object { new Uri(), action };

methodInfo.Invoke(myClass, methodParams);
```